# Restrict Sharepoint List Items

Tags: sharepoint

I have a web part on my home page for SharePoint announcements. On my announcements I have a public / private option.

I want my web part to show private options to users who are a member of a certain permission group.

how would I do this?

Answer (score 1):

You would have to do two web parts on the same page and set the audience targeting on the web part to cover the two groups. The user should only see the web part if they're a member of whichever group. As an example (with made up group names) a web part might target members of 'Managers' the other would target 'Employees'. Each would only see one web part.

If the two groups aren't separate presently, you'd have to go through Central Admin to create any missing audiences that include or exclude users as necessary.

Comment: That is great and has helped with my web part. The only issue I have now is that the web part allows the user to navigate to the full list. How would I do the restriction on the list.

Comment: A few options. 

1) If its the web part's title link that is allowing them to link to that, you can just hide that in the chrome type by setting it to None.
2) If you wanted to keep the data seperated into different lists (and thus easy to secure) You can use a Content Query web part to merge the two into one view in the web part. They would only see the ones they're allowed to see.
...

Comment: ...or 
3) You can use audience targeting on the list items, as described <a href="http://www.mssharepointtips.com/tip.asp?id=1135&page=4">here</a>. Short story: go to list settings > Audience Targeting > Enable. Then go back to the list and you now have a columnn where you can specify which audiences can see that item. While precise, it does require you input the audiences into the item (via form or workflow)